# Using Flask I pass a text to my html file, which contains a link with html format of a link, but the code has been shown instead of a link

Tags: html, flask, hyperlink

I am working with Flask. My code read an excel file and save some part of a text from this excel file in a variable called "answer." Then I use this variable in my HTML file.

In my HTML file, I have:

```
{%for ans in answer%}
<p>{{ans}}</p> 
{% endfor %}
```

This "ans" variable contains a text = "please check Google" but it is not shown in my HTML page as "please check Google," where Google has a hyperlink and should go to the link when we click on. Instead it shows the "please check Google" . How can I fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you're trying to do but maybe using

```
<a href="https://www.example.com"> {{ ans }} </a>
```

should do the job.